# How can I add NLTK 'wordnet' on TravisCI ?

Tags: python, github, travis-ci

I want to use `wordnet` for a repository on TravisCI, currently it's giving me following error :

[image]

How can I download `wordnet` on TravisCI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing: 
`install:
- pip install -r requirements.txt`

to :
`install:
- pip install -r requirements.txt
- python -c "import nltk; nltk.download('wordnet')"`

worked!